# Why the condition from localstorage doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, storage

In the template component `AppComponent`, depending on the value, the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` switches between the `logIn()` and `logout()` methods, which in the application component `AppComponent` are subscribed to these methods in the service `LoggedinService` and depending on the method, change the value of the variable to true or false.

Also in the Guard's method `checkLogin (url: string)` I return true or false depending on the value of the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn`

**Everything works, but when I reset the page, I need to keep the value of the input or output button. I try to do this in the `login()` and `logout()` methods in the service, but after reloading the page, the changes are still not saved. Help solve this problem so that the changes remain after the page reboot.**

**template of AppComponent:**

```html
          <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success"
                   [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   (click)="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? logout() : logIn()">
                    {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
                </a>
            </li>
```

**code of AppComponent:**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService,
            private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {}

logIn(): void {
    this.loggedInService.login();
    if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
        let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl :
            '/gallery';
        this.router.navigate([redirect]);
    }
}

logout(): void {
    this.loggedInService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
}
```

**LoggedinService:**

```js
export class LoggedinService implements OnInit {
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    redirectUrl: string;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.CheckAuthentication();

    }
    enter code here
    CheckAuthentication(): boolean {
        if (localStorage.getItem('login') === 'true') {
            return this.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else if (localStorage.getItem('login') === 'false') {
            return this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    }

    login() {
        localStorage.setItem('login', 'true')
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('login');
        localStorage.setItem('login', 'false')
    }
```

**AuthGuard:**

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot):  boolean{
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.loggedInService.redirectUrl = url;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem('login');` why would `localStorage.getItem('login')` on the very next line return anything other than `null`? It seems like a multi-threaded guard but I don't think it'd work in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change is `isLoggedIn` to be `get` method base on localStorage item

```
export class LoggedinService implements OnInit {

    redirectUrl: string;

    constructor() {}

    get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
       return localStorage.getItem('login') ? true : false;
    }

    login(){
     localStorage.setItem('login','true') 
    }

    logout(){
     localStorage.removeItem('login') 
    }

}
```

*app.component*

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  logIn(): void {
      this.loggedInService.login(); // set the state as login
      let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl :
        '/gallery';
      this.router.navigate([redirect]);
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.loggedInService.logout(); //// set the state as logout
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgxrpz)

Comment: remove this from the template (html)       `(click)="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? logout() : logIn()">
                    {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}`

Comment: @IgorShvets have you update appComponent => this.loggedInService.login() not login and logout normal methods

Comment: Yes i do this can you show example of you approach in StackBlitz ?

Comment: It 's better if you create the example base on you code then I will update it

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt with your code.

In LoggedInService `onInit` why are you calling `login()` and `logout()` directly?

```
this.CheckAuthentication();
this.login();
this.logout();
```

Doing that is adding and deleting from your **localStorage**. Also, you can check data in your local storage by typing `localStorage` in browser console.I think you should comment or remove `onInit` method

Comment: I need save  the value of "guard" and  button; deleting "ngOnit" does not change anything

Comment: Instead of referencing `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` in **AppComponent** html, you can call `this.loggedInService. CheckAuthentication()` or get this value once in **AppComponent** `ngOnInit()` and store as `isLoggedIn` variable in **AppComponent**